# Delete excel rows based on latest date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to maintain a list of docs (see below) with only their latest revision.

However, my file shows some doc#s having multiple revs. I need to be able to do a one-time delete of rows of old revs for each document. One option is to somehow use the issue date of each doc# for comparison. Only the row with the latest issue date stays.

Can anyone pls show me how to do this? Is there a better approach than my option above?

Still starting w/ excel vba but can comprehend quickly. My original list has around 4000 rows so solving this will be most helpful. Thx...Jeff

```
Doc    Rev    Issue Date  
A      6      5-Oct-2013  
A      5      1-Sep-2013     (Delete)  
A      4      1-Jun-2013     (Delete)  
B      1      3-Oct-2013  
B      0      4-Jul-2013     (Delete)  
C      3      1-Oct-2013  
C      2      9-Sep-2013     (Delete)  
C      1      8-Aug-2013     (Delete)  
C      0      6-Jun-2013     (Delete)
```

Comment: Alternatively to VBA you could do this with native Excel (using a formula, autofilter, delete)...

Comment: Hi Peter. Can you pls elaborate. Thx...Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your scenario, you can do this without VBA. Assuming your data is in cells `B2:D10`, this approach should work:

1. In E2, place the formula `=MAX($B$2:$B$10*($A$2:$A$10=A2))<>B2`. Enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copy it down to `D10`
2. Now apply an AutoFilter and filter column D for `TRUE`
3. Delete all rows and removed the autoFilter

Answer (score 0):

MAKE A SAVED COPY OF WORKBOOK FIRST!

Assuming your headings are in row 1 and your data starts in row 2 and the Doc is on column A...

Add a formula in a new column on row 2 like this

```
=IF(A2=A1,"(Delete)","")
```

Not copy that formula down the row. The rows to delete will have the work "(Delete)". If few in number, just manually delete. If more, read on.

Next part is funny, bu copy that column and paste SPECIAL as VALUES in another new column. Sort by this and your deletes are all together to select as range and delete.

Comment: This will only work, if the list is sorted by documents with the latest revision on top! Instead of the Value copy and sort, better just apply an AutoFilter and delete everything after the filtering...

Comment: Thanks, @PeterAlbert. With the info provided, I went with the sample the user had which seemed to be sorted in the order he wanted them deleted.

Comment: I tried Peter's instructions to the letter including sorting with the latest rev on top. I found some rows being marked "Delete" when their issue dates are actually most recent. I'll keep checking my steps but hopefully someone can help as well.

Comment: oops. i actually meant having issues with asanta's instructions. I'm trying Peter's approach as well.

Comment: Sounds good to try @PeterAlbert's first since it's more general purpose. If you do come back, are you sure that you have sorted by Doc _then_ Issue Date? Also are you sure you did sort before writing the formulas(s)

Answer (score 0):

I like Peter's solution as a non VBA way. If you want to use VBA then the following works.

You start by sorting by Doc and Date and then iterating over the list and deleting all but the most recent:

```
Sub GetLatestVersion()
    Dim data As Range, i As Integer

    Set data = Range("A1:C9") //Change appropriately
    data.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("C1"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    For i = data.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If Range("A" & i - 1) = Range("A" & i) Then
            Range("A" & i - 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```